# Animate a rectangle into a half heart shape using css

Tags: html, css, css-animations, pseudo-element, css-shapes

The animation moves the shape down first and then left, instead of going diagonally. I am going wrong in the animation timing or perhaps the positioning of the elements.I understand it is just animating shapes which has already been covered in many posts. I am finding it tricky with animating the shape with the pseudo element. Appreciate the help.

```css
.container {
  background-color: black;
  height: 500px;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

.firsthalf
/* this is going to turn into the bottom of the half heart shape */

{
  height: 0px;
  width: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  right: 0px;
  top: 25px;
  border: 25px solid green;
  animation-name: heart-bottom1;
  animation-duration: 3s;
}

@keyframes heart-bottom1 {
  0% {
    top: 25px;
    right: 0px;
    border-radius: 25px solid green;
  }
  50% {
    border-bottom: 25px solid transparent;
    border-right: 25px solid transparent;
    top: 200px;
    left: 100px;
  }
  100% {
    top: 25px;
    right: 0px;
  }
}

.firsthalf::before
/*this is going to turn into the upper part(the spherical bit) of the half 
      heart*/

{
  content: "";
  background-color: green;
  height: 25px;
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 25px;
  left: -25px;
  animation-name: heart-up1;
  animation-duration: 3s;
}

@keyframes heart-up1 {
  0% {
    height: 25px;
    width: 50px;
    border-radius: 0;
  }
  50% {
    border-radius: 25px 25px 0 0;
  }
  100% {
    border-radius: 0;
    height: 25px;
    width: 50px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="firsthalf">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can You please paste the code to codepen ? I'll be much easier to help You

Comment: Thanks. Here it is https://codepen.io/Punsajan/pen/YzyrBqr

Comment: Simply replace `left: 100px` in your animation with `right: YourOffsetInPx` in your animation keyframe.
For the creation of the heart shape you could have a look at [this nice tutorial from Geoff Graham](https://css-tricks.com/hearts-in-html-and-css/). If you're still stuck, please elaborate more precisely at which point.

Comment: Thanks Uchendu it did the job. I don't understand how I didn't catch that, noob here. Someone commented here before, which is deleted now, asked me to remove the same(left: 100px) but I thought I needed it to offset it sideways, without realising which side.
Anyways thanks heaps.